# Decide if denesting is at all possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

> Denesting the two numbers
>   $$\sqrt{1\pm\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}$$
>   should be straightforward—supposed *it is at all possible?*

When following the ansatz
$$\sqrt{1\pm\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}\;\overset{!}{=}\;p+q\sqrt2$$
one is led to solve
$$p^2+2q^2=1\quad\text{and}\quad pq=\pm\frac14$$
$\ldots$ and the cat catches its tail since
$$p^2\;=\;\frac12\left(1\pm\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\;\right)$$
and similar for $q^2$.

---

I came across this after diagonalising a positive-definite matrix whose positive square root is needed in a proof somewhere else.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+sqrt(1+%2B+sqrt(2)%2F2)) says the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt2}2}$ over the rationals is of degree $4$, which should mean that it cannot be written of the form $p+q\sqrt2$ for rational $p, q$. Do you have any reason to believe that it is possible?

Comment: @Arthur No, I haven't. I'm not experienced with stuff like this; I was simply striving after 'simpler' expressions for the square roots of 'my' eigenvalues.

Comment: @Arthur  Would you like to expand on what that means, the 'minimal polynomial of the given radical expression'?

Comment: For any algebraic number (including radical expressions), there is a _minimal polynomial_, i.e. a _smallest_ polynomial (measured by degree) for which that number is a root. Any other polynomial for which that number is a root is divisible by that minimal polynomial (this is a generalisation of "$a$ is a root of $f$ iff $f$ is divisible by $x-a$": in that case, $x-a$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$). If a number $t$ can be written on the form $p +q\sqrt2$, then we have $t^2 - 2tp + (p^2 - 2q^2) = 0$, so whatever the minimal polynomial of $t$ is, it divides some second degree polynomial.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks a lot for your mini-lecture!! Now pacified I shall write $n_\pm$ and proceed with my proof elsewhere 
$\ddot\smile$

Comment: Note, however, that the minimal polynomial of the same number may differ depending on what coefficients are allowed. For a concrete example, $2x^4 - 4x^2 + 1$ is the minimal polynomial of your $n_+$ if we only allow _rational_ (or integer) coefficients, while $x-\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt2}2}$ is the minimal polynomial if we allow real coefficients. If we only allow coefficients which are of the form $p + q\sqrt 2$ with rational $p, q$, then the minimal polynomial is $x^2 - \left(1 + \frac12\sqrt2\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *decide* if it's possible, that's easy: it would mean there is a rational solution of $8p^4-8p^2+1=0$. If $p=a/b$ with coprime integer $a,b$, it's known that $a$ must be a divisor of $1$, and $b$ a divisor of $8$, so it's a rather easy to check all cases.